# Need help with abusive user "Flater"

Tags: support

User "Flater" has posted an abusive answer on my question.

[Why is some technology in Star Wars so primitive?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91636/why-is-some-technology-in-star-wars-so-primitive/)

His tone is combative and hostile, and has poisoned the well for this question making it impossible to get good answers. Their attitude is not constructive or helpful.

I am trying to fix the question but it is difficult when the first response anyone sees is this patronising abusive one. Because of the subsequent trolling I can't even down-vote it.

The flagging system is useless and opaque. How can we deal with abusive, combative users like this?

Comment: Do you know you can flag their post to notify moderators about their behaviour? Did you try it?

Comment: I did try flagging, it hasn't really helped. Aside from anything else the text box is too small to write an explanation in and you can't really dialogue with them, so I'm asking here where it's possible to have an actual conversation.

Answer (score 9):

Frankly, the referenced main site question and your behaviour on it **is a mess**, together with this finger-pointing and combative meta post.

What happened was that you asked a question that wasn't well-received by the community (and later closed) and got a genuine answer trying to answer it and explain the discrepancy you ask about in the question.

You didn't agree with the answer (and the question was closed) so you then took it upon yourself to issue flags marking it as "not an answer". But I'm afraid, **it's a genuine answer**. You not agreeing with it doesn't make it not an answer nor abusive.

Together with this you also issued about a million comment flags marking comments that answer your requests for clarification as **"abusive", which they're not**. Again, you simply flagged one side of a genuine comment discussion about the question and its answers simply because you didn't agree. I deleted a bunch of comments from everyone that became irrelevant and some comments from you that were downright rude, but the moderators are not going to be your tool for quenching discussion just because you don't agree with what's said.

I'd implore you to **stop the blatant flag abuse and move on**. All it does is paint *you* as an abusive and combative user, I'm afraid.